# EF core configuration for self referencing list

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, entity-framework-core, ef-core-5.0

I'm having some trouble trying to configure some entity with self reference. My entities looks pretty much like the following:

```
public class MainEntity 
{
  public Guid Id {get; private set;}
  ...
  public IReadOnlyList<Foo> Foos => _foos;
  private readonly List<Foo> _foos {get; private set;} = new List<Foo>();
}
public class Foo
{
  public Guid Id {get; private set;}
  public Guid MainEntityId {get; private set;}

  public IReadOnlyList<Bar> Bars => _bars;
  private readonly List<Bar> _bars {get; private set;} = new List<Bar>();
  
}
public class Bar
{
  public Guid Id {get; private set;}
  public Guid? FooId {get; private set;}
  public Guid? ParentBarId {get; private set;}

  public IReadOnlyList<Bar> Bars => _bars;
  private readonly List<Bar> _bars {get; private set;} = new List<Bar>();  
}
```

So basically the `MainEntity` has list of `Foos` which has list of `Bars` with possible inner `Bars` list (you can look at MainEntity as some user profile; Fools as list of user posts; Bars as comments of a post or replays of some parent comment)

Initially I thought everything was fine, but later noticed that by doing `context.MainEntities.Include(x => x.Foos).ThenInclude(x => x.Bars).First();` I only get first layer of Bars (that has FooId) and somebar.Bars is always empty.

I could use `ThenInclude(x => x.Bars)` multiple times but that doesn't really make sense since max depth isn't limited and would hurt a retrieval performance.

I tried having Bar.FooId ar not nullable and populate it but had no luck (`context.SaveChangesAsync()` couldn't resolve the relationship, probably because of missconfiguration in modelbuilder). Also im not sure if it won't cause additional issues like `Foo` containing all of `Bars` with `FooId` even tho `Bar` has `ParentBar`...

*Sometimes my explanations can be confusing, so let me know if any clarification is needed.*

Comment: As far as I'm aware, you can't use eager loading to achieve this. You'll either have to manually specify a depth for the query to know how many times to join to the table, or use lazy loading to automatically perform N+1 queries for each depth you traverse.

Comment: A work around that comes to mind could be to add another guid to Foo that would be propagated to all Bars that follows. So two db queries would do a trick: `context.MainEntities.Include(x => x.Foos).First()`and then `context.Bars.Where(x => mainEntity.Foos.Select(xx => xx.Guid).Contains(x.Guid)).ToList()` but i consider this hacking and Guids should be passed down manually

Comment: The issue you'll have with that is the serializer won't know what depth the record is at thus you'll have all the records but under one layer of depth. I assumed you wanted to preserve the object nesting but if you can get by with just using the ID then thats a fine solution.

Comment: So the additional Guid prop would not have reference and serializer should figur out depth by FooId and BarId values. As far as i know it should work but I would like to avoid this hack

Comment: Have you considered using a library that adds CTE support to EFC? https://linq2db.github.io/articles/sql/CTE.html or raw'ing/view'ing a recursive cte: https://khalidabuhakmeh.com/recursive-data-with-entity-framework-core-and-sql-server

Comment: Need to see your model config. That will determine what is going wrong. If you do not have a model config: that is probably what is going wrong. More complex stuff like this usually needs the way it builds the DB to be explicitly defined in the model builder.

Comment: You should un nullable FooId, then you cann find all bars of any foo, if it errors, that is another problrm,but if you set correctly FooId of all Bars it should has no errors.then after selecting all Foos that you want,and all bars of each Foo, by a simple function you can organise all bars nestedly

Answer (score 1):

So, the solution is very simple. Firstly I will demonstrate the way I **modified** the entities:

```
public class MainEntity
{
   public Guid Id { get; set; }

   public string Name { get; set; }

   public IReadOnlyList<Foo> Foos { get; set; }
}

public class Foo
{
   public Guid Id { get; set; }

   public string Name { get; set; }

   public Guid MainEntityId { get; set; }

   public IReadOnlyList<Bar> Bars { get; set; }
}

public class Bar
{
   public Guid Id { get; set; }

   public string Name { get; set; }

   public Guid? FooId { get; set; }

   public Guid? ParentBarId { get; set; }

   public virtual Bar ParentBar { get; set; } 
   public virtual ICollection<Bar> ChildrenBars { get; set; }
}
```

As you can see, I also added **ParentBar** field, that has a type of **Bar**.

Next step is to ovveride the **OnModelCreating** method in your **AppDbContext** class as depicted below:

```
...

public DbSet<MainEntity> MainEntities { get; set; }

public DbSet<Foo> Foos { get; set; }

public DbSet<Bar> Bars { get; set; }

protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
   modelBuilder.Entity<Bar>()
           .HasMany(b => b.ChildrenBars)
           .WithOne(b=>b.ParentBar)
           .HasForeignKey(b=>b.ParentBarId);    
}
```

And **finally**, in your controller, you can call the **MainEntites** like next:

```
return await _context.MainEntities.Include(me=>me.Foos)
            .ThenInclude(me=>me.Bars).ToListAsync();
```

**This**, will return you a response as shown below:

[image: api response]

I hope my **answer** was useful and helpful!